# How to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\cos(b(x-c)^2)\,dx$?

Tags: integration, analysis

In my research, the Gaussian-like integration $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\cos(b(x-c)^2)\,dx$ stumps me a lot. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much, sincerely.

Comment: Write $\cos b(x-c)^2$ as the real part of an exponential.

Comment: $2 \cos(b(c - x)^2)=e ^{i b ( x − c )^2} + e^ {− i b ( x − c )^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a,b>0$, we want to compute

$$\operatorname{Re}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left(-ax^2+ib(x-c)^2\right)\,dx\\=\operatorname{Re}\left[\exp\left(\frac{abc^2}{b+ia}\right)\int_\mathbb{R}\exp\left(-(a-ib)\left(x+\frac{ibc}{a-ib}\right)^2\right)\,dx \right]$$
which by shifting the integration line simply equals
$$ \operatorname{Re}\left[\exp\left(\frac{abc^2}{b+ia}\right)\int_\mathbb{R}\exp\left(-(a-ib)x^2\right)\,dx \right]=\operatorname{Re}\left[\exp\left(\frac{abc^2}{b+ia}\right)\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{a-ib}} \right]$$
or
$$ \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{(a^2+b^2)^{1/4}}\,\exp\left(\frac{ab^2 c^2}{a^2+b^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{b}{a}-\frac{a^2 b c^2}{a^2+b^2}\right).$$