# Finding a solution to a PDE arising from using Feynman's trick of differentiating under the integral sign

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, improper-integrals

When considering possible generalisations of the improper integral
$$\int^\infty_0 e^{-x^2} \cos (x^2) \, dx,$$
(for its evaluation see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458055/about-integration-int-infty-infty-e-x2-cosx2-dx)) one that immediately comes to mind is
$$u(a,b) = \int^\infty_0 e^{-ax^2} \cos (bx^2) \, dx, \quad a > 0, b \in \mathbb{R}.$$

This integral can be readily evaluated using complex methods. But if we confine our attention to using only real methods, employing a method reminiscent of the most common way used to evaluate the Gaussian integral, by squaring the integral before converting it to polar coordinates similar to what was done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458055/about-integration-int-infty-infty-e-x2-cosx2-dx/2524357#2524357), one finds
$$u(a,b) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \sqrt{a + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}. \tag1$$

---

As an alternative (real) method to squaring the integral one can try Feynman's trick by differentiating under the integral sign.

Differentiating with respect to $a$ one has
$$u_a(a,b) = - \int^\infty_0 x^2 e^{-ax^2} \cos (bx^2) \, dx.$$
Differentiating with respect to $b$
$$u_b(a,b) = - \int^\infty_0 x e^{-ax^2} \cdot x \sin (bx^2) \, dx,$$
followed by a single integration by parts gives
$$u_b (a,b) = -\frac{1}{2b} u(a,b) + \frac{a}{b} \int^\infty_0 x^2 e^{-ax^2} \cos (b x^2) \, dx = -\frac{1}{2b} u(a,b) - \frac{a}{b} u_a(a,b),$$
which after rearranging becomes
$$2a u_a + 2b u_b + u = 0. \tag2$$

Two boundary conditions for the above first-order semi-linear partial differential equation can be found. They are
$$u(a,0) = \int^\infty_0 e^{-ax^2} \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4a}},$$
and
$$u(0,b) = \int^\infty_0 \cos (b x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8b}}.$$

> I understand the method of characteristics may be used to find a solution to (2). If this is correct can someone show me how this can be done so we arrive at (1). If not, what other method(s) could be used to find a solution to (2)?

---

I should add if the limits of integration are extended to all $\mathbb{R}$, a further generalisation of the improper integral can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521139/how-to-calculate-int-infty-inftye-ax2-cosbx-c2-dx) where it was evaluated using a very slick and simple complex method.

Comment: The complex analysis method is to say $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-sx^2}dx = s^{-1/2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=s^{-1/2}  \sqrt{\pi}$ is true for $s > 0$, thus by analytic continuation it is true for $s \in \mathbb{C}, \Re(s) > 0$. Your integrals are solved with $s = a\pm ib$

Comment: Yes, I know this. The complex methods are very slick and handle this problem with easy, but as I say in the question, I am looking to confine myself to purely real methods only. I have provided one approach and are looking to see how a second alternative (real) approach would work.

Comment: The characteristics flow in the direction $(a,b)$, which flows *along* your boundary where $a=0$ or $b=0$. This means your boundary is characteristic (i.e., does not satisfy the "noncharacteristic condition"), and the method of characteristics will not work.

Comment: You actually get four solutions to the given PDE
 
\begin{align}
u_{1} &= f \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) a^{-1/2} \\
u_{2} &= f \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) a^{-1/2} \\
u_{3} &= f \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) b^{-1/2} \\
u_{4} &= f \left( \frac{b}{a} \right) b^{-1/2}
\end{align}

where $f$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.

Comment: @Mattos - The four solutions you give do not seem to satisfy either of the two given boundary conditions. Would I be correct in thinking this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the part about the boundary conditions. And you're right, none of the solutions satisfy them.

Comment: Let $v(\theta)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\sin(\theta) x^2}\cos(\cos(\theta)x^2)dx$ for $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$.  If $a=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin\theta$ and $b=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos\theta$, then $u(a,b)=(a^2+b^2)^{-1/4}v(\theta)$, so you could try to find an ODE for $v(\theta)$ using Feynman's trick, given the boundary conditions $v(0)=\sqrt{\pi/8}$ and $v(\pi/2)=\sqrt{\pi/4}$.

Comment: How did you get the result in $(2)$? Integration by parts on $u_b$ gives

$$ u_b = -\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-ax^2}\cdot x\sin(bx^2)\ dx = \left. \frac{1}{2b}xe^{-ax^2} \cos(bx^2) \right|_0^{\infty} + \frac{a}{b}\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-ax^2}\cos(bx^2)\ dx \\ = -\frac{a}{b}u_a $$

Comment: @Dylan - In the $u_b$ integral set $u = xe^{-ax^2}$ and $dv = x \sin (bx^2)$. Remember the product rule needs to be applied to $u$ when differentiating it.

Comment: Forgot about that. Thanks